# How do I replace a multiple sets of characters with a single character

Tags: java

I want to replace multiple sets of characters with a single/multiple characters.

example :

input

> i want hello RRRRRRRRRRRR My name RRR is RRRRRRRR arvind RR

output

> i want hello A My name A is A arvind A

Is there any library method that would allow me to do this?

The only way I can think of doing it is to loop through each character and see if the next character is the same. I would note the beginning and end index and recursively perform this operation on the string till the end.

Comment: You will need to use regex for this purpose

Comment: "(\\w)\\1+" - this would be the matching regex.

Comment: i tried regexes out only after asking this question. This is a nice website to test regexes. http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and this is as nice explanation on regexes http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: @kocko thanks for your quick answer. Because all of you have given the same solution, I have upvoted your solutions and marked mine as the correct in order to be fair to all.

Comment: @Ruchira thanks for your quick answer. Because all of you have given the same solution, I have upvoted your solutions and marked mine as the correct in order to be fair to all.

Comment: @FaceOfJock - thanks for your quick answer. Because all of you have given the same solution, I have upvoted your solutions and marked mine as the correct in order to be fair to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String input = "i want hello RRRRRRRRRRRR My name RRR is RRRRRRRR arvind RR";
String output = input.replaceAll("R+" "A")
```

Comment: Why answering your own question with the actual copy of another answer and writing "try this"?? :)

Comment: @ConstantineNovykov - i actually tried it out and answered it.  it struck me after i asked the question. Try this was added in the edit history. Please down the edit instead of my answer.

Comment: @constantine ... It would be great if you could undo the downvote if it was you who did it. Thanks

Comment: I tried, but it is unfortunately locked, so I've made a couple of upvotes for your other questions. If you accept my edit on this answer, I will be able to undo the downvote.

Comment: @ConstantineNovykov - i was not able to see your edit but i removed the text "try this" ... thanks for upvoting some of my other questions .. i hope they were actually useful ... :)

Comment: They were. I didn't do it just for fun.. :) Removed the downvote.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [String#replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. It consumes a **regex** as a first argument and the replacement for every match found.

```
String s = "i want hello RRRRRRRRRRRR My name RRR is RRRRRRRR arvind RR";
String result = s.replaceAll("R+", "A");
```

Comment: can i ask you a doubt

Comment: Be my guest, @newuser :)

Comment: How it work if the value contains any thing like ARRIVED, ARRAY.

Comment: Well, it will, because the OP wants to replace sets of characters with a single character. In your example, `RR` is a set of characters, isn't it ? :)

Comment: @kocko i understand you mentioned OP.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this. `R+` will replace one or more `R`

```
    String str = "i want hello RRRRRRRRRRRR My name RRR is RRRRRRRR arvind RR";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("R+","A"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this , A will replace 2 or more RR in your string :

```
String str = "i want hello RRRRRRRRRRRR My name RRR is RRRRRRRR arvind RR";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("R{2,}", "A");
```

Answer (score 0):

[StringUtils.containsOnly](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#containsOnly%28java.lang.String,%20char%5b%5d%29)

```
String[] split = s.split(" ");
            for (String value : split)
            {
                if (StringUtils.containsOnly(value, "R"))
                {
                   value = value.replace(value, "A");
                }

                System.out.println(""+value);
            }
```

Because if any of the value contains `ARRIVED`. It only replace the multiple R's as A. But you want to replace if only R's in a word.